# Mininum 1 char, Minimum 4 char, Maximum 50 char

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Instead of using `mb_strlen` and `preg_match`, I'm trying to devise a purely regex solution, so that I can shorten my code by piping everything through a function.

*Minimum Possible Input (number chars are only used to demonstrate quantity)*

- `1@1234`

*Maximum Possible Input (number chars are only used to demonstrate quantity)*

- `123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345@1234`
- `1@123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678`
- and everything in between like `123456790@123456789012345678901234567890123456789`

**The current pattern I've devised is `^.{1,}?@.{4,}?$`, but I'm not sure how to limit the total characters to 50?**

I've tried capturing and grouping everything (e.g. `(^.{1,}?@.{4,}?$){,50}`, `[^.{1,}?@.{4,}?$]{,50}`), but these obviously don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding a negative lookahead at the start of the pattern which asserts that no more than 50 characters appear in total:

```
^(?!.{51,}).{1,}?@.{4,}?$
```

### Demo

The negative lookahead `(?!.{51,})` literally asserts that we *don't* see 51 or more characters, which then implies that there *50* or fewer characters present.

Comment: i gotta wait 8 mins to mark as solved

Comment: Maybe you will get another answer.  What I suggested is probably the easiest way to do it though.

Comment: The pattern already must have at least 6 characters, because of the `@` combined with `{1,}` and `{4,}`.  The negative lookahead also ensures no more than 50 characters in total.  What is the actual behavior you want?

Comment: nevermind. im just not thinking straight right now. this works fine for the time being. sorry about that

Comment: `im just not thinking straight right now` ... sounds like myself on a Monday morning `:-)`

Comment: lol thats me around this time every evening